# Using multiple if else to check for content and member status

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to check if a user is logged in as a member and also if a meta field in a WordPress custom post type has content and then need to display content based on 4 possible outcomes. I am using WordPress membership plugin woomembers

1. user is logged in as a member and content exists - display content
2. user is logged in as a member and content field is empty - display nothing
3. user is not a member and content exists - display some content and sign up
4. user is not a member and no content exists - display sign up

I have this code partly working but can't get item 3 to work?

The code I have is:

```
<?php $meta_content_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, "meta-content-field", 
$single = true);

   if (wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships() && 
   $meta_lighting_diagram != '') { 

       // Active member and has content- do something here

       ?>
       html content here

   <?php
   } elseif (wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships() && 
   empty($meta_content_field) ) {

        // No content but active member - do something here
        echo "No content but active member";

   } elseif ( ! empty( wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships() ) && 
   ($meta_content_field) ) {

       // content but non-member - do something here - this is not working? 
       echo "Has content but NOT active member";    

   } else {  

        // Non-member - do something here ?>
        html content here                                       

  <?php }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is wrong. First check should be member or not.

```
if ( $member) {
 // do something for the member
} else {
 // do something for the non-member
}
```

Then you want to check whether or not there is content.
Do this within the if-loop

```
if ( $member ) {
 // do something for the member
  if ( $content ) {
   // member and content
  } else {
   // member no content
  }
} else {
 // do something for the non-member
  if ( $content ) {
   // non-member and content
  } else {
   // non-member no content
  }
}
```

a maybe even better approach would be to use `switch()`. Could look like this:

```
$status = '';    
if ( $member ) $status = 'member';
  else $status = 'nonmember';
if ( $content ) $status .= 'content';
  else $status .= 'nocontent';

switch ( $status ) {
   case 'membercontent':
        // do something
        break;
   case 'membernocontent':
        // do something
        break;
   case 'nonmembercontent':
        // do something
        break;
   case 'nonmembernocontent':
        // do something
        break;
}
```

This can be simplified (shortened) in combination with `default:`.